# how to explode the database values in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter

```html
set_time_limit(0);
$config['upload_path'] =  'datauploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = '*'; // CSV|csv|xlsx|xls
$config['max_size'] = '0';
$config['max_width']  = '0';
$config['max_height']  = '0';
$config['overwrite']  = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file_upload'))
{
 $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
 print_r($error);
}
else
{
 $file_name = $this->upload->file_name;
 $datas = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
 $handle = fopen(base_url()."datauploads/$file_name", "r");    
 $fp = $handle;
 $BufferString= @fgets($fp ,4096);
 $BufferString   = explode("\n",$BufferString);
 $childDropdown = array();
 $childDropdownArr = $this->dform_model->edit_field($modId,$recId);
 $childDropdown = explode("|",$childDropdownArr['def_value']);
 
 while (($datas = fgetcsv($handle,1024*30, ",")) !== FALSE) 
 {  
  $displayName = $datas[0];
  $databaseValue = $datas[1]; 

  if(!in_array($databaseValue,$childDropdown[$displayName]))
  $childDropdown[$displayName][] = $databaseValue;     
 }
}
```

Here I have written some code to update the new excel value with existing one in the def_value column of table, I have def_value value like this (0,US,US,|0,Monali,Monali,|), here I need to explode the both 0 and | from text. I have explode the value like this $childDropdown = explode("|",$childDropdownArr['def_value']); but it's not working for explode both values. How to do that using codeigniter can any one please help me..

Comment: Post expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

$text = "(0,US,US,|0,Monali,Monali,|)";

$exploded = multiexplode(array("0","|","|0"),$text);

print_r($exploded);
```

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#111307